# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, azure-mobile-services

I am trying to update a users hours for an attended club. I was able to do it once before, but now I always get the same error of Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 409 (Conflict). This is troubling to me because I am updating with the correct id and it should work. Another problem is it does not give me enough information in the error to know what is happening. That is why I'm asking for help. Thank you in advance.

The service where the error is coming from

```
.service('hourAdder', function(){

    return{

addHours:function(userID,meetingID){
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('My mobile Service');


        client.getTable('Meeting').where({id: meetingID}).read().done(function (results) {
        var hours = results[0].Hours;
        var points = results[0].Points;
        var club = results[0].ClubID;
        console.log("Hours:" + hours+" Points:"+points+" Club:"+club);


        client.getTable('AttendedClubs').where({id: club,UniqueUserID: userID}).read().done(function(hoursPoints){

        points = points + parseInt(hoursPoints[0].Points);
        hours = hours + parseInt(hoursPoints[0].Hours);

        client.getTable('AttendedClubs').update({id: club,UniqueUserID: userID, Hours: hours, Points: points}).done(function(updated){



    }, function(error)
    {


        console.log("Updating Hours Errors"+ error);

    });


    }, function(error)
    {


        console.log("Getting Attended Clubs"+ error);

    });



    }, function(error)
    {

        console.log("One of the poeple returned an error");


    });




}
}
})
```

Comment: Its hard to know what the conflict is without understanding whats happening serverside.  They say that 409 conflicts typically happen when what you are doing conflicts with the current state of the server.  The server may not want you to update this resource anymore, or maybe the resource has a new id. Yet again, its hard to tell without having a better understanding of the black box that is your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for an update operation to work, the version you last downloaded on the client MUST be the same version as the version on the server.  i.e. the version fields (exposed by the ETag header in the response and the version property in the object) MUST match. If they don't, you get a conflict.

Check out https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/25/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-12-conflict-resolution/ for details on how to handle conflicts.

I also note that you are not using a Singleton for your MobileServiceClient.  Check out https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter6/angular/ for some hints on how to use the MobileServiceClient in an Angular app.  Specifically, note that you should place the MobileServiceClient in a factory so that it becomes a singleton in your app.

Comment: Thank you for helping and telling me about singletons!! I have already implemented that into my code. Now as for the conflict I think I have an idea to why this is happening but don't know how to fix it. In my server I made the id and UniqueUserID a unique duo.... meaning the combination of the two must be unique. I think when trying to update this it gives me an error. However if it is the versioning I am not exactly sure how to fix that. I tried adding the version in the update call but that didn't work. Thank you @Adrian Hall

Comment: This page: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-js-client/blob/master/offline-sync.md - covers conflict handling in the JavaScript and Cordova SDKs.

Comment: I made sure the versions stayed the same and it worked!!! Thank you!!! @Adrian Hall